# Check jdk/JRE is installed and get path for jvm.dll

Tags: java, c++, jvm

Prgrammatically, how to check if java is insalled and get path from jvm.dll ?

Comment: Short and dirty answer? Run it and see if it works

Comment: Check the registry. If you read the registry, you can tell where it is installed.. Windows only. Don't know for linux.

Comment: Check out [Launch4j](https://sourceforge.net/projects/launch4j/) or [JSL](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jslwin/) to see how they search the Windows Registry for an installed JVM

Answer (score 3):

**[Location of VM Library Files (jvm.dll)](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/install-windows-142126.html)**

For Oracle's JDK. The path within the JDK to the Java HotSpot Client VM is:

- jre/bin/client/jvm.dll (on x86)

The path to the Java HotSpot Server VM is:

- jre/bin/server/jvm.dll (on x86)
- jre/bin/server/jvm.dll (on IA64)

**Windows Registry Keys**

Oracle, OpenJDK, Azul, IBM and other JDK developers may use a variety of Windows Registry Keys. For example, Java 11 appears to use the `JavaSoft\JDK` key, while Java 8 uses `JavaSoft\Java Development Kit`. Programs like [Launch4j](https://sourceforge.net/projects/launch4j/) and [Java Service Launcher](http://www.roeschter.de/) search the registry for JVMs.

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\{version}\JavaHome`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Plug-in\{version}\JavaHome`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment\{version}\JavaHome`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\JDK\{version}\JavaHome`

**EDIT**

```
# Recursively search JAVA_HOME for jvm.dll to set JVM_FILE
FOR /R %JAVA_HOME% %f IN (*) DO IF "%~nxf"=="jvm.dll" SET JVM_FILE="%~dpnxf"
```

Answer (score 2):

Java can be installed anywhere, and there is no guarantee that you should be able to see, where. So, the general answer to your question, is *"it is impossible"*, or that *"you had to run a recursive file search for `jvm.dll` on your whole filesystem"*.

But this is not, what you want. I think, you want to get a "default" java or jvm, which will be used by java tools or any java software.

Normally you can find that in the `$JAVA_HOME` environment variable (on windows, `%JAVA_HOME%`) the actual jdk or jre install, which should contain `jvm.dll`.

If it doesn't work, it is a configuration problem on the system, but maybe it can happen. Your second choice should be to find a `java.exe` or a `javaw.exe` somewhere in your system path (`$PATH` or `%PATH%` on windows).

There are a lot of tools, or java softwares which are coming out with their own java/jvm instance, especially oracle like to give out them. In their case, only the general solution works.

Answer (score 2):

You can also Write a Java program that prints out the value of the `java.home` system variable. For example:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.home"));
```

then invoke `java.exe` on this class. If Java is not installed or you can't run it then the process will not start... but if it starts then it'll tell you the path to the JRE installation folder, which is what you need in order to figure out where the jvm.dll is.

There's still the problem of Java being installed but not being on your PATH. In that case, I would just report that Java could not be found and ask the user for additional input.

Comment: my main program is C++ not java!!

Answer (score 2):

This is a snippet of how I did it, the location of the jvm dll will be stored in `runtimeLib`.

```
char version[255];
char runtimeLib[255];
DWORD BufferSize = 8192;
string javaKey = "SOFTWARE\\JavaSoft\\Java Runtime Environment";
if(RegGetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, javaKey.c_str(), "CurrentVersion", RRF_RT_ANY, NULL, (PVOID)&version, &BufferSize) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    //jre not found

javaKey += "\\";
javaKey += version;
BufferSize = 8192;

if(RegGetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, javaKey.c_str(), "RuntimeLib", RRF_RT_ANY, NULL, (PVOID)&runtimeLib, &BufferSize) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    //jvm.dll not found
```

Comment: if(RegGetValue(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, javaKey.c_str(), "RuntimeLib", RRF_RT_ANY, NULL, (PVOID)&runtimeLib, &BufferSize) != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    //jvm.dll not found
...

this retun jvm.dll not found!!

Comment: @BestHumain2 that means your current version has no corresponding folder in the registry. Not really a problem for stack overflow.